Getting an exception with MySQL queries and ExecutorService#submit
I'm trying to make the sql queries asynchronous but I'm getting the following exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
And this is my code:
ResultSetCallable callable = executeUpdate(REGISTER_NEW_ACCOUNT,
                new VarcharColumn("name", name),
                new VarcharColumn("uuid", uuid.toString()),
                new VarcharColumn("rank", PlayerRank.NONE.name()),
                new VarcharColumn("packageRank", PlayerRank.NONE.name())
        );
        Future<ResultSet> future = SQL_EXECUTOR.submit(callable);
        try (ResultSet resultSet = future.get()) {
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                return resultSet.getInt(1);
            }
        }
        catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return -1;

executeUpdate method:
public ResultSetCallable executeUpdate(String query, Column<?>... columns) {
        try (
                Connection connection = getConnection();
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)
        ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                columns[i].setValue(statement, i + 1);
            }

            statement.executeUpdate();

            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                return () -> resultSet;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

And the ResultSetCallable is an interface who just implements Callable.
The SQL_EXECUTOR is static final ExecutorService SQL_EXECUTOR = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();. I'm using HikariCP for connection pooling. So, someone knows why I'm getting this exception, what's wrong with my code or what I should know.
I tried using synchronized and volatile and nothing.

ResultSetCallable and executeUpdate - what library those come from? btw, your code is not asynchronous and never will due to immediate future.get()

ResultSetCallable is a custom class and executeUpdate is a custom method. Sorry i thought it was asynchronous, how could i make it asynchronous and thread-safe?

Your problem is here:
try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
    return () -> resultSet;
}

(Refer to method executeUpdate – in the code in your question.)
resultSet is closed before it is returned since you are using try-with-resources.
Maybe CachedRowSet is appropriate?
Search for java cachedrowset example.

As @Abra points out, your try blocks are closing the result set and connection. However there seems to be little point running only the getInt(1) part in a separate thread - your calling code is running the query and only a tiny part is set to run in another thread.
Instead, a better way to handle the SQL is to perform the entire query as one unit which can be dispatched to executor service, and allowing your calling thread to do other work:
    Callable<Integer> callable = executeUpdate(REGISTER_NEW_ACCOUNT,
            new VarcharColumn("name", name),
            new VarcharColumn("uuid", uuid.toString()),
            new VarcharColumn("rank", PlayerRank.NONE.name()),
            new VarcharColumn("packageRank", PlayerRank.NONE.name())
    );
    Future<Integer> future = SQL_EXECUTOR.submit(callable);
    
    // Do other work here while background SQL is running
    
    // Now block & access the result
    return future.get();

Then move all the query so it is self-contained Callable which runs the statement and gathers the result status:
public Callable<Integer> executeUpdate(String query, Column<?>... columns) {
    return () -> {
        try (
                Connection connection = getConnection();
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)
        ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                columns[i].setValue(statement, i + 1);
            }

            statement.executeUpdate();

            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    return resultSet.getInt(1);
                }
                // Decide between:
                //    throw new RuntimeException("Nothing found");
                //  or
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
}

The above will be easy to test as callable.call() without using executor service.
